# Date Current time doesn't set hh:mm asp net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Here is my code (what i have try) :

```
Dim DataCorrenteLoad As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
TextBox4.Text = DataCorrenteLoad
```

It works fine but i want the current date with hh:mm , example

> 30/05/2017 , 16:21

But with that code the (hh:mm) remain 00:00

e.g :

> 30/05/2017 , 00:00

Someone can help me ? How can i put the correct hour on the date ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Really? You pass it a format string of  `dd/MM/yyyy` and you are expecting it to give you the hours and minutes?

Comment: How can i implement hours and minutes ? Thanks really !!

Comment: Look at my answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the relevant [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Why put me -1 ?  yes thanks

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano I guess because of research, like mason mentioned with the link. It's not that difficult to find the solution of your problem using 2 minutes google.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger I didn't find , anyway him help me.
But this is not a valid reason to downvote my question , i can't open new question.

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano "this question does not show any research effort" so it is. - but I didn't downvote you. Nevertheless, this is basic. You should learn to use a documentation. Search google for "datetime tostring", the first link is the msdn-documentation of `DateTime`s `ToString`-method. There is also an example with `HH:mm`. Somehow this shows me that you didn't search for a solution more than a minute. In conclusion, this is a valid reason to get downvoted. Sorry.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Thanks for the expaination, now i understand your first message and you have right . 6 months ago i didn't research as well , i was a starter developer and new on StackOverflow

Comment: Anyway, now i have to modify my question , to resolve the block about "New Question" and i can't delete question like this because it has got an answer. So the only thing to do is modify as possible. Thanks Again @MatthiasBurger

Comment: Let me explain, with the word "modify" , i meant "explain more, add details .." . This is the only way to improve my downvoted question , as the help center of StackOverflow says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.ToSting()` accepts a format. You need to put `"hh:mm"` in addition to `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Comment: Thanks it works but it show 04:29, now , how to set 16:29 ?

Comment: Simply use `"HH:mm"`.